# Python unable to pass defaultdict values to function

Tags: python, parameter-passing, defaultdict

I have a complex code which reads some values into nested defaultdict.
Then there is a cycle going through the keys in the dictionary and working with them - basically assigning them to another nested defaultdict.

Problem is, when I want to use the values from the dictionary and access them and pass them as values to a function.... I get either empty {} or something like this: defaultdict(<function tree at 0x2aff774309d8>

I have tried to write the dict so I can see if it is really empty. Part of my code;

```
if (not families_data[family]['cell_db']['output']):
        print(rf"Output for {family} is  empty.")
        print(dict(families_data[family]['celldb']))
```

The really fun part is, when this "if" is true, then I get the following output:

*Output for adfull is  empty.
{'name': 'adfullx05_b', 'family': 'adfull', 'drive_strength': 0.5, 'template': 'adfull', 'category': '', 'pinmap': '', 'output': 'CO S', 'inout': '', 'input': 'A B CI', 'rail_supply': 'VDD VSS', 'well_supply': '', 'description': ''}*

if I change the second line in the if to

```
        print(families_data[family]['celldb'])
```

I get the following output:

*defaultdict(<function tree at 0x2b45844059d8>, {'name': 'adfullx05_b', 'family': 'adfull', 'drive_strength': 0.5, 'template': 'adfull', 'category': '', 'pinmap': '', 'output': 'CO S', 'inout': '', 'input': 'A B CI', 'rail_supply': 'VDD VSS', 'well_supply': '', 'description': ''})*

Why is the "if" even true, when there is a value 'CO S' in the output key?

Why am I getting {} when trying to access any value like families_data[family]['cell_db']['input'] and passing it to function as a parameter?

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cell_db" key in the if statement has an underscore while it does not in the print statement.

This should fix it:

```
if (not families_data[family]['celldb']['output']):
    print(rf"Output for {family} is  empty.")
    print(dict(families_data[family]['celldb']))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Sometimes all it needs is a second pair of eyes. I was worried there that defaultdict works in some mysterious ways. :-D